# Open Calendar in Android

Tags: android, calendar

How to open Calendar on Button Click and get clickable Date.

Answer (score 4):

check this out: http://www.developer.com/ws/article.php/3850276/Working-with-the-Android-Calendar.htm

EDIT:

To open calendar from button click event add this code to onClick method:

```
Intent i = new Intent();

//Froyo or greater (mind you I just tested this on CM7 and the less than froyo one worked so it depends on the phone...)
cn = new ComponentName("com.google.android.calendar", "com.android.calendar.LaunchActivity");

//less than Froyo
cn = new ComponentName("com.android.calendar", "com.android.calendar.LaunchActivity");

i.setComponent(cn);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Hi evilone Thx. How it is implement on Button Click..?

Comment: @evilone: This is an undocumented, unsupported, and unreliable solution. This application will not exist on all devices, and as you have seen, Google will change how it gets used.

Comment: If i write the above code on button click then it is giving Force Close.

Comment: @CommonsWare Hello sir, is this a feasible(Valid) solution? i am asking as i am also in search of Calendar-view solution. Thanx

Comment: @evilone my current SDK is 2.1 , I am getting this exception: "android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.android.calendar/com.android.calendar.LaunchActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?" ,

Comment: the emulator doesn't have a calendar application so it would not be able to find the application

Answer (score 0):

Try using the CalendarView widget, see docs [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html)

This isn't a dialog, so you'd have to create a dialog, wrap it around a CalendarView and launch it yourself.

Comment: Extend the android.app.AlertDialog in the same way DatePickerDialog does, to wrap the CalendarView widget, see the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html) for AlertDialog for how to add a custom layout to the view