# error in using calendar in android?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to open calendar from my app and using the code below as i found it in this question :[how can i open the calendar from my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034788/how-can-i-open-the-calendar-from-my-app/5035119#5035119) ...but getting following error

> 07-01 14:19:26.299:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14167): Caused
>   by:
>   android.content.ActivityNotFoundException:
>   Unable to find explicit activity class
>   {com.google.android.calendar/com.android.calendar.LaunchActivity};
>   have you declared this activity in
>   your AndroidManifest.xml?

any help will be useful..

```
Intent i = new Intent();
    ComponentName cn = new ComponentName("com.google.android.calendar", "com.android.calendar.LaunchActivity"); 
    i.setComponent(cn); 
    startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Did you see this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104691/open-calendar-in-android

Comment: yes i have seen that one and its similar to what i am using.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried specifying permissions ?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_CALENDAR

or alternatively use:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);  
    intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
    intent.putExtra("title", "Some title");
    intent.putExtra("description", "Some description");
    intent.putExtra("beginTime", new java.util.Date().getTime());
    intent.putExtra("endTime", new java.util.Date().getTime()+36000000);
    startActivity(intent);
```