# How to open native calendar from titanium app?

Tags: titanium, titanium-alloy

how to open native calendar from titanium app for android and iOS? As in, on the click of a button, i want to open the native calendar on the ipad.

Comment: And why? What do you want to do? Simply open the app?

Comment: yes, i have a button called 'View Appointments in Calendar'. on clicking that, the native calendar should open up

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
Titanium.Platform.openURL('CALSHOW://');
```

Comment: This only works on iOS. See asanlo's answer for the android part of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In android you can open it using a native intent, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104691/open-calendar-in-android/5104726#5104726)

There's a difference between versions lower and greater than Gingerbread. There's also a difference in HTC devices because of the HTC Sense Software, as explained at the end of [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/kJo-XYl4WMA) question.

Here is my tested code for Titanium:

```
    if (Titanium.Platform.osname=="android"){

        //Params needed to create the android intent.
        var packageStr = "com.google.android.calendar";
        var classStr = "com.android.calendar.LaunchActivity";
        var actionStr = Ti.Android.ACTION_VIEW;

        var model = Ti.Platform.model;


        if ((model.indexOf("HTC") != -1) || (model.indexOf("htc") != -1)){
            //If it's a HTC device
            packageStr = "com.htc.calendar";
            classStr = "com.htc.calendar.MonthActivity";
            actionStr = Ti.Android.ACTION_MAIN;
        }
        else {
            //For android versions before Gingerbread (2.3)
            var version = parseFloat(Ti.Platform.version);
            if (version < 2.4) packageStr = "com.android.calendar";
        }

        //Launch native calendar
        var intent = Ti.Android.createIntent({
            action: actionStr,
            packageName: packageStr,
            className: classStr
        });
        Ti.Android.currentActivity.startActivity(intent);
    }
```

You can also open the "create event" screen of the native calendar by adapting [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373074/how-to-launch-android-calendar-application-using-intent-froyo) for  Titanium in the same way as the code above

Comment: See Stef's answer for the iOS answer.